# How to change default date and time format of timestamp like from 2015-09-29 10:48:33 To 2015:09:29 10:48:33

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timestamp, load

The following is text file "myfile.txt"

```
7022122465,0,0,day,2015:09:29 10:48:33
7022597642,0,0,day,2015:09:29 10:48:33
7022848906,0,0,day,2015:09:29 10:48:33
```

The above text file i want to store date and time format like 2015:09:29 10:48:33 in database column but default timestamp format is 2015-09-29 10:48:33

I tried  the following query, but I am getting default timestamp format like 2015-09-29 10:48:33

```
mysql  -D obd2 -h 127.0.0.1 -p3306 -uroot -pubona@123456 --local-infile -e "load data local infile 'D:/myfile.txt' into table obdcallattempts2 columns terminated by ',' (phone,mou,isSongSelected,@dummy,@datetime) set attempt_date=DATE_FORMAT('@datetime','%Y:%m:%d %h:%i:%s'),extra=1 "
```

Please help me....
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't store the dates in a format other then the format that already exists.

You can do it while selecting :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.column,'%Y:%m:%d %h:%i:%s'),...
FROM YourTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do that. Date will be stored in the format which you are having internally. You can change the format while retrieving the dates from database.

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) says:

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.